# First brillouin in twisted bilayer graphene

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, graphene

When it comes to the reciprocal space of twist bilayer graphene, there is a very typical picture: [image]

In this picutre it shows the hoppings bewteen the nearest Dirac point between two layers. And there are six hoppings since there are six Dirac points. And these two Dirac points then form the new moire first brillouin zone of the twisted bilayer graphene, as the picture show:
[image]

But I don't understand how the brillouin zone of the twisted bilayer graphene is derived. Because the reciprocal space is not even derived since the moire sublattice is not clear in the arbitrary angle. So how to derive the first brillion in formal for arbitrary angles for twisted bilayer graphene and what the reasonibility of the above picture with respect to TBG?